# Alpha channel fade animation

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

Im pretty new to shaders and I've been attempting to create a shader that would do a alpha revel of a texture and I've gotten close but Im pretty sure there is a much better way.

This is what I have to far https://codepen.io/tkmoney/pen/REYrpV

```
varying vec2 vUv;
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;
        uniform sampler2D texture;
        uniform float mask_position;
        uniform float fade_size;


        void main(void) {
            float mask_starting_point = (0.0 - fade_size);
            float mask_ending_point = (1.0 - fade_size);

            vec4 orig_color = texture2D(texture, vUv);

            vec4 color = texture2D(texture, vUv);

            float mask_p = smoothstep(mask_starting_point, mask_ending_point, mask_position);

            //color.a *= (distance(vUv.x, split_center_point));

            vec2 p = vUv;

             if (p.x > (mask_p)){
                 color.a = 0.0;
             }else{
                color.a *= (smoothstep(mask_position, (mask_position - fade_size), p.x ));
              }



            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
```

the fade in does not completely reveal the entire image as you can see. Any insight on a better way to tackle this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You can use mix, like:
color = mix( vec4( 0 ), color, time ); 
or, make it repeat itself like:
color = mix( vec4( 0 ), color, sin( time ) );
where time is a uniform that comes from the elapsed time since load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to make the area at the left of `mask_position` visible, but you want to hide the are at the right. this can be achieved by [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/step.xml):

```py
color.a *= 1.0 - step(fade_size, p);
```

If you want a smooth transition from the visible to the invisible area, then you have to use [`smoothstep`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/smoothstep.xml). The start of the fading is a certain amount before `mask_position` and the end a certain amount after `mask_position`:

```py
float start_p = mask_position-fade_size;
float end_p   = mask_position+fade_size;
color.a *= 1.0 - smoothstep(start_p, end_p, vUv.x);
```

This will cause that the start and the end of the image will never fade in completely. TO compensate this the [vUV.x] has to be mapped from the range [0.0, 1.0] to the range [`fade_size`,  `1.0-fade_size`]. This can be calculated by [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/mix.xml) with ease:

```py
float p = vUv.x * (1.0-2.0*fade_size) + fade_size;
color.a *= 1.0 - smoothstep(start_p, end_p, p;
```

If the alpha channel of the final culler is below a tiny threshold, the fragment can be discarded:

```py
if ( color.a < 0.01 )
      discard;
```

Final shader:

```py
varying vec2 vUv;
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float mask_position;
uniform float fade_size;

void main(void) {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, vUv);

    float start_p = mask_position-fade_size;
    float end_p   = mask_position+fade_size;
    float p       = mix(fade_size, 1.0-fade_size, vUv.x);

    color.a *= 1.0 - smoothstep(start_p, end_p, p);
    if ( color.a < 0.01 )
        discard;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

See the example:

```js
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var uniforms;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

    camera = new THREE.Camera();
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/background.jpg' );

    uniforms = {
        u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        texture: {type: 't', value: texture},
        fade_size: { type: 'f', value: 0.2 },
        mask_position: { type: 'f', value: 0 }
    };

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
    } );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha : true} );
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0.0);
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    onWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    document.onmousemove = function(e){
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = e.pageX
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = e.pageY
    }
}

function onWindowResize( event ) {
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

var mask_step = 0.01;
var mask_val = 0.0;
function render() {
    if ( mask_val >= 1.0) { mask_val = 1.0; mask_step = -0.01; }
    else if ( mask_val <= -0.0) { mask_val = 0.0; mask_step = 0.01; }
    mask_val += mask_step;
    uniforms.mask_position.value = mask_val;
    uniforms.u_time.value += 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```html
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform vec2      u_resolution;
uniform float     u_time;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float     fade_size;
uniform float     mask_position;

void main() {
    vec2 vUv = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, vUv);
                
    float start_p = mask_position-fade_size;
    float end_p   = mask_position+fade_size;
    float p       = mix(fade_size, 1.0-fade_size, vUv.x);
    color.rgba *= 1.0 - smoothstep(start_p, end_p, p);
    if ( color.a < 0.01 )
          discard;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
```